# Default documents for mongodb (with mongoose) collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So in my little app I have a section where you app shows you a table. And table should be customized according to user's needs. Like you have columns like (number, name, value, date). And user should be able to chose which columns he wants to see. And they should be stored for future use.

Is there a way I can set default settings at mongoose schema or somethingc at start of program, and save them into db.. like

```
{
Name: "name",
Selected: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can achieve this by storing the user selected columns in your users collection rather than storing it in the collection from where you are pulling the table data. So your user schema should be like:

```
{
  ...
  userPreferences: [{
    type: String                   // columns user wants to see
  }]          
}
```

Each time user opens your app, Show him inly the columns present in his preferences. Also there should be a provision in your app for the user to change these preferences.

To fetch only the selected columns from mongo, you can user the query like:

```
your_model.find({}, {name:1, value: 1})
.then(result => {
...
})
.catch(err => {
...
});
```

The second parameter object represents what fields need to be selected from document.

Hope this helps :)